# GNU tar not ignoring directories in gitignore with --exclude-vcs-ignores

Tags: tar, gnu-tar

I have a git repo: `rsh`:

```
❯ cat rsh/.gitignore
*.o
shell
build/
rsh_history
```

And I'm attempting to tar it up using tar (GNU tar) 1.32.

The command I'm using is:

```
❯ gtar cvaf rsh.tar.gz --exclude-vcs-ignores --exclude-vcs rsh
```

Unfortunately, the `build/` directory is included in the tarfile, in spite of `build/` being specified in the .gitignore.

```
❯ gtar cvaf rsh.tar.gz --exclude-vcs-ignores --exclude-vcs rsh
...
rsh/build/
rsh/build/meson-private/
rsh/build/meson-private/install.dat
rsh/build/meson-private/meson.lock
rsh/build/meson-private/sanitycheckc.exe
rsh/build/meson-private/build.dat
rsh/build/meson-private/sanitycheckc.c
rsh/build/meson-private/cmd_line.txt
rsh/build/meson-private/meson_benchmark_setup.dat
rsh/build/meson-private/meson_test_setup.dat
rsh/build/meson-private/coredata.dat
rsh/build/compile_commands.json
rsh/build/rsh
rsh/build/rsh@exe/
rsh/build/.ninja_deps
rsh/build/build.ninja
rsh/build/meson-logs/
rsh/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
rsh/build/meson-info/
rsh/build/meson-info/intro-buildsystem_files.json
rsh/build/meson-info/intro-benchmarks.json
rsh/build/meson-info/intro-buildoptions.json
rsh/build/meson-info/intro-dependencies.json
rsh/build/meson-info/intro-installed.json
rsh/build/meson-info/meson-info.json
rsh/build/meson-info/intro-tests.json
rsh/build/meson-info/intro-projectinfo.json
rsh/build/meson-info/intro-targets.json
rsh/build/.ninja_log
...
```

Curiously enough, the .gitignore itself does get ignored (--exclude-vcs); as well the other files in the .gitignore (rsh_history).

Comment: it might be a difference in interpretation of the .gitignore file.  try either `build/*` or `build/**` rather than just `build/`.

Comment: @cas neither of those worked; not did `build/**/*`

Comment: try `**/build/*` - that's the only way I've been able to get it to exclude an entire subdirectory.  note: this will also exclude build/* found in any lower level subdirs.

Comment: `**/build` and `build` also seem to work (and match non-directories too). I would add these workarounds additionally to the `.gitignore` with a comment like `# needed for tar --exclude-vcs-ignores`

Comment: if you write that up as an answer, i'll upvote it and you can accept it in a day or so.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, both `build` and `**/build` work.

It should be noted though that this will also match in subdirectories. And as far as I've seen (someone please edit this answer if you know better), there is no way around this through either the `.gitignore` file or a simple command line option. Because tar doesn't understand either the leading slash syntax of git (so e.g. `/build` to match only `build` in the root directory), nor `!` inclusions (e.g. `!but_i_want_this_included/build`).

The [official docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html) say:

> `.gitignore`
>
> Contains shell-style globbing patterns. Applies to the directory where
>   `.gitfile' is located and all its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only exclude directories in the same directory as the `.gitignore` file, you can add two rules in `.gitignore`:

```
#
# exclude log directory in the same directory as .gitignore
#

# - for git
/log/

# - and for the linux shell
./log
```

This way, git uses the entry with the leading `/` and does not match `./`.

Shell-tools like `tar` on the other hand, can't handle leading `/`, but can interpret `./`.

So your original command with the option `--exclude-vcs-ignores` will work.

There is one problem though:

> This will only work, if you run `tar` from the same directory, where the
>   `.gitignore` file is located. 
>   It will not work for other `.gitignore` files in directories below.

Comment: will accept after confirming